# How can I do movements with widgets in ScreenManager when I reach the screen that holds the objects?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy-language

I just want to move the ball or any other object when I move to that level screen that is MainWindow...
The next program below this one does something relative that I want but that's not having different screens...
Here is the code...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.graphics import Rotate, Rectangle, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    def loginbtn(self):
        sm.current = "stage"


class StageWindow(Screen):
    def nextpage(self):
        sm.current = "main"
        game = MainWindow()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game

class MainWindow(Screen):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    object = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = 40, 310
        self.ball.velocity = vel
        print('served')

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.object.deflect_ball(self.ball)
        if (self.ball.y < self.y):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
        if (self.ball.top > self.top):
            print('Done')

    def start(self):
        self.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

class Object(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 300
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 50
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)


    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
        self.angle += 90
        print(self.angle)

    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            if self.angle == 135:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
            else:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
            print('collided')

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()
            print('hi')

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('clicked')

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()


screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), StageWindow(name="stage"), MainWindow(name="main")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GameApp().run()
```

Kivy file for one above is...

```
WindowManager:
    StageWindow:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:

<StageWindow>:
    name: "stage"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.04, "y":0.3}
            size_hint:1.0, 1.0
            text: "Stage>>"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            text:"1"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.nextpage()
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            text:"2"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.nextpage()
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.4,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            text:"3"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.nextpage()
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.6,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            text:"4"
            on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.nextpage()
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.8,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            text:"5"
            on_release:
                root.manager.direction = "down"
                root.nextpage()


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"


    FloatLayout:


        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            text: "Play"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.loginbtn()


<MainWindow>:

    ball: pong_ball
    object: Object


    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        size: 50, 50
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,0,1,1
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        center: self.center


    Object:
        id: Object
        center: self.rotate_origin
```

It is that one that shows something I want to do when I reach MainWindow...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Rotate, Color, Rectangle, Ellipse
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string('''

<PongGame>:
    name:"game"

    ball: pong_ball
    object: Object


    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        size: 50, 50 
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,0,1,1
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size 
        center: self.center


    Object:
        id: Object
        center: self.rotate_origin


''')

class Object(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 300
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 50
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)


    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
        self.angle += 90

    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            if self.angle == 135 :
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
            else:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)
            print('collided')

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):`enter code here`
            self.rotate()

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)


    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos



class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    object = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = 40, 310
        self.ball.velocity = vel
        print('hi')

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.object.deflect_ball(self.ball)

        if (self.ball.y < self.y):
            self.ball.velocity_y *=-1
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
        if (self.ball.top > self.top):
            print('Done')


    def start(self):
        self.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

I know that there are so many problems here that I have to sort-out but firstly please solve this one...

Thanks

Comment: Please minimize the problem to what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want to make the ball move as it moves in the second program in my first program when I reach to that screen that holds these objects...Thanks for helping me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer that I found myself from other questions of stack overflow...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, CardTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.graphics import Rotate, Rectangle, Ellipse, Color
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string('''
<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    object: Object

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.center

    Object:
        id: Object
        center: self.rotate_origin


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    Screen:
        name:"P"
        FloatLayout:


            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
                size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
                text: "Play"
                on_release:
                    root.transition.direction = "up"        
                    root.current = "stage"

    Screen:
        name: 'Loading'
        MyWidget:                

    Screen:
        name: "stage"
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                pos_hint:{"x": 0.04, "y":0.3}
                size_hint:1.0, 1.0
                text: "Stage>>"

            Button:
                pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":0.05}
                size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
                text:"1"
                on_release:
                    root.transition.direction = "right"
                    root.current= "Game";game.serve_ball()


    Screen:
        name: 'Game'
        PongGame:
            id: game

''')


class Object(Widget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Widget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.rect_pos_x = 500
        self.rect_pos_y = 300
        self.rect_pos = self.rect_pos_x, self.rect_pos_y
        self.rect_width = 200
        self.rect_height = 50
        self.rect_size = self.rect_width, self.rect_height
        self.rotate_origin_x = self.rect_pos_x + self.rect_width / 2
        self.rotate_origin_y = self.rect_pos_y + self.rect_height / 2
        self.rotate_origin = self.rotate_origin_x, self.rotate_origin_y
        self.angle = 135
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0,197,68))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)


    def rotate(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Rotate(origin=self.rotate_origin, angle=self.angle)
            Color(rgb=(0, 255, 100))
            Rectangle(pos=self.rect_pos, size=self.rect_size)
        self.angle += 90

    def deflect_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            if self.angle == 135 :
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(90)
            else:
                ball.velocity = Vector(-vx, vy).rotate(270)


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.rotate()

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    object = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)


    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = 40, 310
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()


        self.object.deflect_ball(self.ball)

        if (self.ball.y < self.y):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
        if (self.ball.top > self.top):




class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

sm = Manager()

class ScreensApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScreensApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what is going on here with this, however if I'm understanding your question, you want to know how to start an animation when you enter a certain screen.

For this you can use the following Screen methods: on_pre_enter, on_enter, on_leave, on_pre_leave.
These are listed in the https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html API, and are the first events listed.

Hopefully this helps you get where you're going.

An example using your code:

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    object = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4, 0)):
        self.ball.center = 40, 310
        self.ball.velocity = vel
        print('served')

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()
        self.object.deflect_ball(self.ball)
        if (self.ball.y < self.y):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
            self.ball.velocity_y = 0
        if (self.ball.top > self.top):
            print('Done')

    def start(self):
        self.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 60.0)

    def on_enter(self):
        self.serve_ball()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you help me little more by sharing any example involving these methods or can you just copy and run these codes and find what's wrong with this code and why I am not able to do animation on the screen as I did on separate code given above...

Comment: I have included an example with your MainWindow. As you can see, when you enter the window/screen it should call the serve_ball method of that screen. You can also use it to call functions of your app class as you normally would. eg:
`def on_enter(self): app.yourFunction()`

Comment: Thanks but even doing the changes as you did I am getting the same thing I was getting before...Can you please help me by telling me something more...

Comment: You need to be more clear with what’s happening. are you receiving errors? If so what errors. Unfortunately most people don’t have the time or effort to go through and reproduce your whole code and fix all the bugs. W

Comment: Actually I am not getting any error but the output is not acceptable...what I want is a small ball widget of size 50,50 should move from left to right collide with rectangle that is at angle which will change the direction of ball towards downward...but what's actually happening is large ball of size covering whole screen moving little bit...when I resize it, its position changes...and that's why I am saying to see run second code to see nearly something I want..Thanks for your cooperation...